# Cannot delete records from filing in C++

Tags: c++, binary

I am coding a little program for university. I want to delete a saved record of employee. When I enter the id of the employee and delete it, it seems to have been deleted. But when I check the record, it is still present there. I can not figure out why. Here is the code:

```
system("cls");
more = 'y';
while ((more == 'y')||(more == 'Y'))
{
    faculty = fopen("Employee.txt","rb+");
    temp = fopen("temp.txt","wb+");
    rewind (faculty);
    cout<<"Employee ID: ";
    cin>>xid;
    while (fread(&em, empsize, 1, faculty) == 1)
    {
        if (xid != em.id)
        {
            fseek(temp, 0, SEEK_END);
            fwrite(&em, empsize, 1, temp);
        }
        else 
            found=1;
    }
    fclose (temp);
    fclose (faculty);
    remove ("Employee.txt");
    rename ("temp.txt", "Employee.txt");
    if (found == 1)
    {
        //faculty = fopen("Employee","rb+");
        cout<<"Delete another record (Y/N). ";
        cin>>more;
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\""<<xid<<"\" ID does not Exist.\n\t\t\tDelete                    another record (Y/N). ";
        cin>>more;
    }
    if (more == 'n')
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\tTaking you back to HR .. \n\t";
        system("pause");
        HR ();
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: `I can not figure out why`  Why not?  You wrote the program. so debug it to see where the program is not doing what you're expecting. .

Answer (score 0):

Before your while loop you need to set the value of `found` to something other than `1`.  If you delete a record successfully, all record deletion requests afterwards will appear successful even though they weren't because the `found == 1` flag is still set.

Comment: But should it not still delete the record? I mean the delete process still goes on..

Comment: @user2978059 You need to fix that `found` issue before asking as to what may happen.  It is obviously wrong since you never reset `found` to 0 (and in your post, you didn't even show where `found` is set before the loop).

Comment: @user2978059 - It should still delete the record, but without a functioning `found` flag you have no way of knowing if it intended to or is just saying it so.

Comment: Accessing uninitialized memory leads to undefined behavior.